# Zonal statistics to get majority pixel value per polygon in R?

Tags: r, r-raster

Actually I try to calculate the major pixel values from a raster with a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. Here is some code I found which might lead in the right direction:

```
library(raster)
# Create interger class raster
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18)
r[] <- round(runif(ncell(r),1,10),digits=0)
r[]<-as.integer(r[])
# Create two polygons
cds1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-160,5), c(-60, 0), c(-160,-60), c(-180,-20))
cds2 <- rbind(c(80,0), c(100,60), c(120,0), c(120,-55), c(80,0))
polys <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cds1)), 1), 
Polygons(list(Polygon(cds2)),2))),data.frame(ID=c(1,2)))

# Extract raster values to polygons                             
( v <- extract(r, polys) )

# Get class counts for each polygon
v.counts <-lapply(v,table)
```

So far everything is fine but I´m really stuck to extract the column name of the column which has the highest counts.

I tried things like:

```
v.max<- lapply(v.counts,max)
```

But there the column information gets lost. After:

```
v.max<- lapply(v.counts, max.col)
```

I get just "1" as result.

I´d appreciate if somebody can give me a hint what I´m doing wrong. Is there also another way to extract the major pixel values in a polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`which.max()` is your friend. Since you just want the names, use `names()`.

```
sapply(v.counts, function(x) names(x)[which.max(x)])
# [1] "9" "5"
```

*Note:* `set.seed(42)`

Comment: Can you tell me how I can use the classification direct in the raster::extract() function? I tried: extract("Raster","Polygon",function(x) names(x)[which.max(x, na.rm=TRUE)]) But I get the Error: Error in fun(res[[i]], na.rm = na.rm) : unused argument (na.rm = na.rm)     Where shoud I place the na.rm?

Comment: `which.max` doesnt't have an argument `ra.rm=`, try `which(x == max(x, na.rm = TRUE))` instead. See `?which.max`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This also doesn´t work, I get the same error message. Also setting `na.rm = TRUE` outside the function argument creates the same error. Also using the help examples as template lead to the same result.

Comment: Could you edit your question with a data example that actually fails?

Comment: I guess that would not be fitting in my original question but running: `v <- extract(r, polys,function(x) names(x)[which(x==max(x, na.rm = TRUE))])` on the dataset from the question generates the same result.

Comment: Ok. Read `?extract`: _"`fun`: The function should take a single numeric vector as argument and return a single value (e.g. mean, min or max), and accept a na.rm argument."_ I think your attempt should start exactly there.

Comment: I'm not sure if your names, i.e. character approach is right. It seems to work in numerical form like so: `v <- extract(r, polys, fun=function(x, ...) which(x == max(x, ...)))`. The `...` passes the `na.rm=` argument of the `extract()` function to the function defined in `fun=`.

Comment: Maybe I should formulate a new question about this topic...The result I need at the end is a single value representing the major/dominating class in the polygon. (Like QGIS zonal statistic plugin). I try to get the information by extracting all values and further processing...Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`exactextractr`](https://github.com/isciences/exactextract) package can do this trick. It computes zonal statistics even faster than `terra` in some cases. See comparison [here](https://tmieno2.github.io/R-as-GIS-for-Economists/extract-speed.html)

```
library(exactextractr)
exact_extract(r, polys, 'majority')

#> Warning in .exact_extract(x, sf::st_as_sf(y), ...): No CRS specified for
#> polygons; assuming they have the same CRS as the raster.
#> |======================================================================| 100%
#> [1] 4 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `modal` function

```
v <- extract(r, polys, modal)
```