# Zonal statistic calculating pixel share and determine the most frequent class in R

Tags: r, r-raster

I already posted a related question here: [Zonal statistics to get majority pixel value per polygon in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59554551/zonal-statistics-to-get-majority-pixel-value-per-polygon-in-r) , but this time I want to determine the pixel-class with the highest share on the weights in different polygons in a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. (Similar to QGIS Plugin: zonal statistic > majority) For statistical reasons in my real data set I want to assign the major class at the end to each polygon to the @data slot.

Having some code:

```
set.seed(6)
# Create interger class raster
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18)
r[] <- round(runif(ncell(r),1,10),digits=0)
r[]<-as.integer(r[])
# Create two polygons
cds1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-160,5), c(-60, 0), c(-160,-60), c(-180,-20))
cds2 <- rbind(c(80,0), c(50,30), c(60,0), c(60,-25))
polys <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cds1)), 1), 
Polygons(list(Polygon(cds2)),2))),data.frame(ID=c(1,2)))

# Extract raster values to polygons                             
v <- extract(r, polys, weights = TRUE)
```

So far everything is fine, but in the further question I just had one vector of values for each list element, so it was possible to count the frequency and determine the name of the class with the highest share.

This time I have two columns in a list :
(How is this kind of data-structure inside the list called? Is it a matrix or just the list index?):

```
[[1]]
...
[[2]]
     value      weight
[1,]    10 0.066071429
[2,]     9 0.085714286
[3,]     8 0.098214286
[4,]     4 0.026785714
[5,]     4 0.178571429
[6,]     2 0.098214286
[7,]     3 0.178571429
[8,]     2 0.107142857
[9,]     3 0.137500000
[10,]     3 0.005357143
[11,]     6 0.017857143
```

How would I be able to run for example `dplyr::group_by()` and `summarise()`. I tried different approaches with  `dplyr::summarize_at` but I am to confused how to handle this data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your `v` list is that each entry is a class `matrix` object. Therefore, you need to transform each list entry to `data.frame`, before being able to use `dplyr` functions.

```
library(dplyr)

#Each entry in the list is a matrix object
class(v[[1]])
#[1] "matrix"

#Thus, you need to transform every entry to data.frame
v<-lapply(v, function(x) as.data.frame(x))
#Then set a name for every list entry, in order to use bind_rows
names(v)<-c("1","2")
#use bind_rows
df<-bind_rows(v, .id = "id")
#Get the most frequent class and its frequency
df %>%
  group_by(id,value) %>%
  count() %>%
  ungroup()%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  summarize(most_freqclass = value[which(n == max(n))],
            max_freq = max(n))
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I need!

Comment: Maybe a small note on the grouping part I modified the code to:                      `x<-df %>%
  group_by(id,value) %>%
  count()%>%
  ungroup()
#Omit cases where share of pixel values has the same amount
x[!duplicated(x[,c("id","n")]),]%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  summarize(most_freqclass = value[which(n == max(n))],
            max_freq = max(n))`  Because in my dataset it happens that I have the same share of pixel values in one polygon and dplyr::summarize just works with unique values.